# Compressing large byte arrays while maintaining similarity

Tags: arrays, compression

I have two large byte arrays with around 40000 bytes each. The arrays are around 90% similar. I want to compress them as much as possible while still being able to find that they are around 90% similar by comparing the compressed arrays. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

You can build an optimal Huffman for both of them and then use it to compress them. It's not 100% guarantee that all similar parts will be the same, however, it's close to 100% if that is enough.

Comment: close to 100% is enough. I will check it out